# Odoo Warning - Missing Record Record does not exist or has been deleted . While creating new customer

Tags: odoo-9

[Here is the screenshot of the warning which is apperaing while creating customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI1V7.png)

I am not able to create new customers in odoo.
Initially I have done some customization in my module ...after that customization my code worked absolutely right, I have created new customers also..but after I dont know why i am not able to create new customers...
please suggest me some solution.
Thank you

Comment: did you find the solution for you problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem related to a customized module in Odoo 10.  I did some pretty thorough research and the Odoo ORM is doing some things it probably shouldn't be and that I'm not smart enough to sort out.

The sections in the [Odoo 10 ORM API Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html) about creating models and fields were kind of helpful, but the documentation on the ORM is severely lacking and in some cases incorrect.

I eventually fixed it by doing the insert manually with the `self.env.cr` [psycopg2 cursor](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html) available in the model's custom methods.

That would look something like the

```
from odoo import models

class your_class(models.Model):
    def custom_create_method(self):
        self.env.cr.execute("""
            INSERT INTO customer_model_name
                (name, value, other_value)
            VALUES
                ('{}', '{}', '{}')
            RETURNING id;
        """)
        new_id = self.env.cr.fetchone()
```

This has the disadvantage of introducing the possibility of an SQL injection attack into your code, so you'll need to be careful of that.

This is definitely not the ideal solution, but it does work.  I believe the problem to be related to the Odoo ORM's handling of computed fields, but that is just a not-really-all-that-educated guess at what's going on.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason we found a pattern where we had to comment out one of the dependancies, reinstall/update the module in question, then put it back in. In this case it was `res` in the custom module's `__manifest__.py`

i.e.:

```
  'depends': ['base', 'res', 'sale_management', 'account', 'account_payment'],
    #'depends': ['base', 'sale_management', 'account', 'account_payment'],
```

Becomes:

```
  #'depends': ['base', 'res', 'sale_management', 'account', 'account_payment'],
    'depends': ['base', 'sale_management', 'account', 'account_payment'],
```

Then install, see if the error goes away, then shut down the server and flip the comment again